# How can I change class on :checked on a div including the checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hover

I want to disable the `:hover` effect when `:checked` on a div including my checkbox.
I've tried :

`input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #mydiv:hover {my:css}`

It works only for div/class non including my checkbox...

How can I do that ?

Here is my code :
http://codepen.io/casimirp/pen/gxfqE?editors=110
And I want to change the `#card:hover{
    top:50px;}`

Thanks

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: It's not clean, but there it is : http://codepen.io/casimirp/pen/gxfqE?editors=110 // I want to disable the `top:50px;` on the card div

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#card` is a parent of the input checkbox type.  You can't select a parent element relative to its child.  However, since your checkbox is hidden anyway you can just move it somewhere else, i.e. as a previous sibling of `#card`.  Then, you will be able to select `#card` via `:checked ~ #card` and remove the `top`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/maDjp